# TabView causes duplicate tabview items and list

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

Sorry if this is formatted incorrectly, this is my first time posting here.

I am learning the basics of SwiftUI and I'm having trouble with TabView. My code works fine until I add the TabView portion and then the todo list get repeated and the TabView bar get repeated as well. I've looked over the code and can't see what's wrong with it. I have a MainView, HomeView, CalendarView, and SettingsView views with HomeView being the only view with code written. The rest have only an empty string.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State var toDoList = ["Calendar", "Life", "School", "Habits", "Relationships"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
                List {
                    Section(header: Text("To Do List")) {
                        ForEach(toDoList, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                                .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                                    Button("Archive") {}
                                        .tint(.orange)
                                    Button("Save") {}
                                        .tint(.green)
                                    Button("Junk") {}
                                        .tint(.blue)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .navigationTitle("To Do List")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar() {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                        Button() {
                            
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                        Button() {
                            
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        
        TabView {
            HomeView()
            .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
            
            CalendarView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Calendar", systemImage: "calendar")
            }
            
            SettingsView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape.fill")
            }
                
        }
    }
}




#Preview {
        HomeView()
}
```

[This is how it looks when TabView has been commented out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezZyU.png)
[Image showing repeating of todo list and TabView bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEebA.png)

I have tried to clean the build folder and even created a new project to see if I had residual files hidden from other small projects but those attempts didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The TabView seems to be creating versions of itself, It is in the HomeView so when you click on the tab you get 2. Also having a NavigationStack and the TabView at the same level is kind of unusual.

Answer (score -1):

**This code uses the HomeView as a tab inside the ContentView and thus creates only one TabView view. If you want to add other sheets, you can add new sheets inside the TabView.**

import SwiftUI

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State var toDoList = ["Calendar", "Life", "School", "Habits", "Relationships"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("To Do List")) {
                    ForEach(toDoList, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                            .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                                Button("Archive") {}
                                    .tint(.orange)
                                Button("Save") {}
                                    .tint(.green)
                                Button("Junk") {}
                                    .tint(.blue)
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationTitle("To Do List")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar() {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button() {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button() {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .tabItem {
            Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
            //Other pages can be added here.

            CalendarView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Calendar", systemImage: "calendar")
                }
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gearshape.fill")
                }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct YourApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```